# How can I form a question for "It recurs every n days"?

Tags: questions

> It recurs every n days.

I want to form a question to which the answer is 'n'.  How can I form the question?

Comment: Anything wrong with "How frequently does it recur?"

Comment: @Urby: That could be an answer.

Comment: @Muhammad: His answer exists forthwith.

Comment: If someone else will upvote my answer, I'll delete it and earn a badge!

Comment: Ha!  Now no one can accuse me of being undisciplined! :-)

Comment: @drm65 We wouldn't dream of it. lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you ask the question...

> How frequently does it recur?

...you would expect the answer "every n days".